# Sorting with Mathematical Formula with nHibernate (C#)

Tags: nhibernate, createcriteria

```
public class Feedback
{
 public virtual int Id { get; private set; }    
 public virtual string ContentText { get; set; }
 public virtual DateTime FeedbackDate { get; set; }
 public virtual Student student { get; set; }
}
```

My Feedback Class.

```
public class Student
{
 public virtual int Id { get; private set; }    
 public virtual int NumberOfStars { get; set; }
 public virtual IList<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; private set; }

 public Student()
 {
  Feedback = new List<Feedbacks>();
 }
}
```

My Student Class

```
public class Course
{
 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    // bla bla bla
 public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; private set; }

 public Course()
 {
  Students = new List<Student>();
 }

 public IList<Student> SortBy(string type)
 {
  // some other sorting
  else if (type.Equals("popular")){
   sortedStudents = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Student))
    .CreateAlias("Student", "s")
    .CreateAlias("s.Feedback", "f")
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc( -------- ))
    .List();
  }

  return (IList<Student>) sortedStudents;
 }

}
```

My Course class

I want sort students in a Course with method SortBy :
if type is x i will sort with following rule
(Students.Feedback.Count)*5 + Student.NumberOfStars)

How ?

Comment: does it need to be criteria? It's much easier in HQL.

Comment: Can you write both in HQL and Criteria ?

Comment: Sure, you can use whatever you want for each query. I would prefer HQL, unless you need dynamic queries (this means: when the structure is defined at runtime).

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you put this into a property of the entity. Very bad idea. Put it in some service.

Comment: Hi; Stefan can you explain your comment "I just saw that you put this into a property of the entity. Very bad idea. Put it in some service". Sorry, but I did not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query with LINQ

```
IList sortedStudents = (from student in this.Students
                        where student.Course == this
                        orderby (student.Feedbacks.Count*3 + student.NumberOfStars)
                        select student).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not HQL, this is Linq.

Comment: By the way, this depends on the students you already have in your entity. You could write this much simpler and you don't need a query for it.

Answer (score 3):

HQL:

```
List<Student> sortedStudents = session
  .CreateQuery(
    @"from Students student
      where student.Course == :course
      order by size(student.Feedbacks) * 3 + student.NumberOfStars")
  .SetEntity("course", course)
  .List<Student>();
```

`size` is a HQL function. See the [chapter "Expressions"](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-expressions) in the NH documentation.

You may also select it with Criteria and sort it with Linq.

**Edit**

Just saw that you use it in a property and you *may* have the students already in memory.
You don't need a query, just to sort it.

```
return students
  .OrderBy(x => x.Feedback.Count * 5 + x.NumberOfStars)
  .ToList();
```